# How to navigate the directory of my computer while using adb?

Tags: adb

I want to download recovery onto my phone and to do that I need to open a command window in the folder. However, I run into problems when I try to do that. I already downloaded minimal adb and bootloader and because of that I cant open a regular cmd in the folder. In the adb itself I do not know how to navigate directories and I get confused fast when I try to Google the same question. Thats Why I want to ask all of you. How do you navigate directories in adb?

Comment: minimum adb recognizes regular paths, just use `adb push D:\folder\recovery.img .`

Comment: But MTP mode is faster than adb.